# android Relative Layout issue with list view containing checkboxes

Tags: android, android-layout

i have Relative Layout in my code in which i used i list view containing each item check box. 
i am  using **LayoutInflater** with it. 
i want to add a **Bytton** which is only one time. 
but when i add button with it is comes up with all items of list but it  which should only at the bottom of screen only once.
here is XML of layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

the issue is that i want to add a button also in it. AnyHelp plz

Comment: sorry i didn't get your issues ?

Comment: basically i m getting contacts of phone with list view in which each item have a check box and i want to get checked contacts with clicking the button. but when i add the button in layout it is showed against each item but i want it only once not with each item.

Comment: mean you need only button in checked item out of 5 if 2 is checked then button should be in only 2. am i right ?

Comment: no sir i want button once in screen which should separate from list view and at the bottom of screen after  list view and by clicking the button i want to do action on checked items of list.

Comment: can you show me images how you want ?

Comment: Please post the image what do you want...

Comment: if u do't mind can give ur mail id i will send the source code.

Comment: you can add button in your main xml below listview, if you are not using ListActivity.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the button under your list in the xml layout *containing the list*, **not** in the layout for the list rows (which is what it sounds like you are trying to do now)...

The following will put a header at the top of the list, a button at the bottom and fill the space in between with the list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/header1"
        android:layout_above="@id/button1">
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And then the layout for your list rows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:textSize="25sp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listitem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: where to fix check box in the layout. because i have check box with each item.

Comment: That goes in the xml you specify when you call the list adapter.  I've added an example to my answer.